# Find the equation of a budget hyperplane in R4, from an endowment point and a price vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, economics

> 1. Suppose a consumer has a consumption space with 4 goods, so that we are in $\mathbb R_+^4$. Suppose further that the consumer's endowment is $(10,7,1,25)$ and that se faces the price vector $(6,3,9,2)$.
>
>    1. What is the equation of the budget hyperplane (ignoring the restriction to positive consumption for now)?
>    2. What would be the easiest way to denote the set of all feasible consumption vectors (the frontier of the budget set of the consumer)?
>    3. Is the consumption $(8,11,3,15)$ affordable? What about $(9,12,0,25)$?

It's been a while since I had to deal with vectors, if someone could help me along with 1.1 that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that this is a mathematical question? Everything is based on specific concepts not known to mathematicians in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add a)**

Imagine the consumer is selling his endowment. The proceeds would be $\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i\cdot x_i = 6\cdot 10 + 3 \cdot 7 + 9\cdot 1+2\cdot 25=140$

The consumer can buy different amounts of goods, wihich satisfy the following constraint:

$6\cdot x_1 + 3 \cdot x_2 + 9\cdot x_3+2\cdot x_4\leq 140$ (budget hyperplane)

**add b)**

If the goods are not divisible, then you have to add the condition

$x_i \in \mathbb N_0$

**add c)**

Insert the values for $x_i$ in the inequality (budget hyperplane). If the inequality holds, then the consumption is affordable. This can be done for both consumption bundles.